# .NET Dynamic Data Many-To-Many with LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, many-to-many, dynamic-data

We have a Dynamic Data site we're using for administration and we currently need a way to manage a many-to-many relationship. There are plenty of examples of how to do this using the Entity framework but none that show how this can be done with Linq to SQL. Does anyone have an idea of whether this is possible and a resource for how to do it?